# Как отсортировать List объектов с двумя полями

Tags: java, list, map

Имеется `List<Consumer> myList`, в котором объект представлен полем `consumer` и полем `termClarification`.
Поля заказчиков повторяются, поля уточнений сроков имеют два типа: "есть", "нет".
Необходимо вывести заказчиков и процент соотношения уточнений сроков.

Я использовал код, который группирует уникальных заказчиков и количество уточнений:

```
Map<Consumer, Integer> consumerMap = new HashMap<>();
for (Consumer object : consumerList) {
    if (consumerMap.containsKey(object)) {
        consumerMap.put(object, consumerMap.get(object) + 1);
    } else {
        consumerMap.put(object, 1);
    }
}
```

Как отсортировать значения в процентном соотношении?

Comment: Я ничего не понял. -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, начиная с Java 8 [`Consumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html) -- это функциональный интерфейс с методом `void accept(T t)`.  Во избежание недоразумений стоит использовать другое название класса, например, `MyConsumer` или `Customer`.

> *Имеется List myList, в котором объект представлен полем `consumer` и полем `termClarification`.*

То есть, *предположим*, что класс <s>`Consumer`</s> можно представить так:

```java
@Data // lombok-аннотация для генерации геттеров/сеттеров/equals/hashCode/toString
class MyConsumer {
    private String consumer;
    private boolean termClarification;
}
```

Для расчёта процента соотношений уточнений нужно вычислить количество объектов, где `termsClarification == true` и поделить на общее количество объектов.  Для накопления статистики можно использовать массив `int[]`.

Для расчёта можно применить Stream API и коллектор `toMap` с функцией слияния.

```
List<MyCustomer> customers; // ...
Map<String, int[]> stats = customers.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        MyCustomer::getConsumer, // ключ - поле consumer
        customer -> new int[]{1, customer.isTermClarification() ? 1 : 0},
        (arr1, arr2) -> new int[]{arr1[0] + arr2[0], arr1[1] + arr2[1]}
    ));
```

Статистика `stats` - хэш-мапа, которая не поддерживает порядок сортировки.
Для сортировки по значениям нужно применить компаратор по значению частоты:

```java
stats.entrySet()
     .stream() // Stream<Map.Entry<String, int[]>>
     .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(
         Comparator.comparingDouble((int[] arr) -> (double) arr[1] / arr[0]).reversed()
         ).thenComparing(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
     )
     .forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getKey() + ": " + (double) e.getValue()[1] / e.getValue()[0]));
```

*Примечание: код не тестирован*

Comment: Спасибо, очень подробно.